# RabbitMQ Over SSL

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

I'm trying to set RabbitMQ to work over SSL.

I have changed the configuration file (/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config) as mentioned in the following link
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html to:

```
# Defaults to rabbit. This can be useful if you want to run more than one node
# per machine - RABBITMQ_NODENAME should be unique per erlang-node-and-machine
# combination. See the clustering on a single machine guide for details:
# http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine
#NODENAME=rabbit

# By default RabbitMQ will bind to all interfaces, on IPv4 and IPv6 if
# available. Set this if you only want to bind to one network interface or#
# address family.
#NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1

# Defaults to 5672.
#NODE_PORT=5672

listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = /home/myuser/rootca.crt
ssl_options.certfile   = /home/myuser/mydomain.com.crt
ssl_options.keyfile    = /home/myuser/mydomain.com.key
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.password   = 1234
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
sudo rabbitmq-server
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: 15: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf: listeners.ssl.default: not found
```

If I remove the above line I get the following error:

```
sudo rabbitmq-server
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: 17: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf: ssl_options.cacertfile: not found
```

It is worth to mention that without the above, SSL configuration, everything works just fine.

Could you please assist?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very important when you request assistance with software that you always state what version of the software you're using. In the case of RabbitMQ, providing the Erlang version and operating system used is also necessary.

In your case, you have (commented-out) environment configuration in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`, as well as RabbitMQ configuration, which is not correct. The following lines must be removed from `rabbitmq-env.conf` and put into the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` file:

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = /home/myuser/rootca.crt
ssl_options.certfile   = /home/myuser/mydomain.com.crt
ssl_options.keyfile    = /home/myuser/mydomain.com.key
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.password   = 1234
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
```

Please also see [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#configuration-files)

Answer (score 0):

in the Rabbitmq.config change the following to listen on 5673

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5673
```